# Django string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, django

Using form i create xml request and receive xml respond that looks like this:

```
<Root>
   <Header>
      <information>info</information>
   </Header>
   <Main>
      <Product>
         <Name>name1</Name>
         <Description>description1</Description>
         <Price>1</Price>
         <Pictures>
            <Picture>url_1</Picture>
            <Picture>url_2</Picture>
         </Pictures>
      </Product>
   </Main>
</Root>
```

Then using this function i convert xml data to dictionary:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict

def etree_to_dict(t):
    d = {t.tag: {} if t.attrib else None}
    children = list(t)
    if children:
        dd = defaultdict(list)
        for dc in map(etree_to_dict, children):
            for k, v in dc.iteritems():
                dd[k].append(v)
        d = {t.tag: {k:v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in dd.iteritems()}}
    if t.attrib:
        d[t.tag].update(('@' + k, v) for k, v in t.attrib.iteritems())
    if t.text:
        text = t.text.strip()
        if children or t.attrib:
            if text:
              d[t.tag]['#text'] = text
        else:
            d[t.tag] = text
    return d

e = ET.XML('''
<Root>
   <Header>
      <information>info</information>
   </Header>
   <Main>
      <Product>
         <Name>name1</Name>
         <Description>description1</Description>
         <Price>1</Price>
         <Pictures>
            <Picture>url_1</Picture>
            <Picture>url_2</Picture>
         </Pictures>
      </Product>
   </Main>
</Root>
''')
```

And store it to database:

```
from pprint import pprint
d = etree_to_dict(e)

pprint(d)
d = etree_to_dict(e)

product = d['Root']['Main']['Product']
r = Product.objects.create()
r.name = product['Name']
r.description = product['Description']
r.price = product['Price']
r.save()
```

And everything worked fine. But when i try to save pictures to database:

```
product_pictures=d['Root']['Main']['Pictures']
  for m in product_pictures:
    p = ProductPictures(
      picture = m['Picture']
    )
    p.product = r
    p.save()
    r.productpictures_set.all()
```

I've got `TypeError` `string indices must be integers, not str` on string `picture = m['Picture']`.
Why does it happen? What i'm doing wrong. Thank you for your answer.

Here is my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
  description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
  price = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

class ProductPictures(models.Model):
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True)
  picture = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

UPD:
here is data from `Local vars`:

```
product_pictures

{'Picture': [{'#text': 'http://images.static.goglobal.travel/images/hotels/67862/2010113161131438.jpg',
              '@Description': ''},
             {'#text': 'http://images.static.goglobal.travel/images/hotels/67862/2010113161132187.jpg',
              '@Description': ''},
             {'#text': 'http://images.static.goglobal.travel/images/hotels/67862/2010113161132406.jpg',
              '@Description': ''}]}

m

'Picture'
d

{'Root': {'Header': {'Information': '1521337'},
          'Main': {'Name': 'name1',
                   'Price': '1',
                   'Description': 'description',
                   'Pictures': {'Picture': [{'#text': 'http://images.static.goglobal.travel/images/hotels/67862/2010113161131438.jpg',
                                             '@Description': ''},
                                            {'#text': 'http://images.static.goglobal.travel/images/hotels/67862/2010113161132187.jpg',
                                             '@Description': ''},
                                            {'#text': 'http://images.static.goglobal.travel/images/hotels/67862/2010113161132406.jpg',
                                             '@Description': ''}]},
                   'RoomFacilities': None}}}
```

Comment: `m` appears to be a string, not a dictionary. Although I can't work out where in your code you make it a string.

Comment: the full error stack please

Comment: Can you print out the contents of the "d" dictionary?

Comment: I'm update my post already

Comment: I update with the "d"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product pictures is an object/dictionary with a single key for pictures so it doesn't make sense to iterate over it. You could just iterate over the `Picture`.

```
for m in product_pictures.get('Picture'):
    p = ProductPictures(
      picture = m.get('#text')
    )
```

Although I suspect there is an issue in the creation of the tree dict that may  be worth debugging further.